# Simplification problem involving conbinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

So, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn-2%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%7Dk%20%5Cleft%28n-1%5Cright%29%5Ek) is telling me that:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n}k \left(n-1\right)^k = n^n − n(n−1)^{n−1} −(n−1)^n$$

But I don't have the paid version, and I have no idea of how to operate to arrive at that result. Could anyone help me clear that out, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the binomial theorem for $(1+x)^n$ is

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k$$

Now, if we set $x=n-1$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
n^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(n-1)^k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n}{k}(n-1)^k+\binom{n}{n-1}(n-1)^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}(n-1)^n\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n}{k}(n-1)^k+n(n-1)^{n-1}+(n-1)^n
\end{align}$$

Solving for the sum of interest gives the expected result

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n}{k}(n-1)^k=n^n-n(n-1)^{n-1}-(n-1)^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that, with the Newton formula, $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(n-1)^k=(n-1+1)^n=n^n.$$ You just have to substract the two last terms to get your result.